# wp_redirect is not working when creating a new post

Tags: wordpress

I create a simple post of the custom post type "tickets" with a custom form and the "wp_insert_post" function. After the post is inserted into the database i want to redirect the user to the page of the new post. In my code i use wp_redirect for this but it is not working. After i send the form, the post is created but there is no redirect:

The simple form:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

The code to create the post and redirect after post-creation:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $rowArguments = array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'tickets',
        );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $rowArguments);

        // GET-TICKET PERMALINK
        $url = get_permalink( $post_id );
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit();

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function redirect($url) {
    ob_start();
    header('Location: '.$url);
    ob_end_flush();
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use 3 different ways instate of `wp_redirect`

1. Using Header

```
header('Location:'. $url);
exit();
```

2. Using JavaScript

```
echo "<script>location.href=$url;</script>";
```

3. Using ob_start() and ob_end_flush()

```
ob_start(); 
header('Location: '. $url);
ob_end_flush();
```